# Change folder font color in CSS

Tags: css, gtk

I am working on adjusting a theme better to my liking in Linux Mint14 w/Nemo.
The only thing left that I want to change is the font color of the icons in folders.
The code that controls it is:

```
GtkWindow {
    color: @fg_color;
}
```

However, if I change @fg_color to say #FFFFFF, it changes the text color of the icons, menu bar text, and the borders on all the windows. I want to keep the borders the default color, and just change the font color.
I tried adding the line:

```
text-color: #FFFFFF
```

and

```
color-text: #FFFFFF
```

Which yielded no results. Is it possible for me to accomplish this?

**EDIT**
Maybe I'm not explaining myself right on this. So here is a pic:
[Before altering color: @fg_color](http://www.codedgraphx.info/tka/Thomas/misc/before.png)
If you notice, the text color in the left pane is a white color, and notice the rest of the text in this folder, to include the top bar, is black. I want to change all the text to that white color.
However, when I tried to change it in the .css file as stated above, it also changed the scroll bar border as seen here, but didn't change the top bar text color:
[after changing to color: #FFFFFF](http://www.codedgraphx.info/tka/Thomas/misc/after.png)

Comment: Does `GtkWindow` select the correct element(s)? Does `@fg_color` return/set the correct `color`, in the correct syntax?

Comment: 'GTKWindow' is a generic element for the entire window/folder. By '@fg_color' return/set the correct 'color', do you mean does it set the global color? Yes it does.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the coding for this is in each page if you are not finding it in the .css. Try inspecting the properties of the code from the front (browser) end. It has to be in their somewhere. Chrome browser offers a pretty good "element properties" inspector which may enable you to trace it. I am guessing it is not pulling from the .css and the icons may even have their own folder. You're positive they are not images right? I only say this as you say you want to "change the font colors of the icons in folders" which is a little confusing to me. It almost sounds like you are talking about images. I hope this comment helps!

Comment: Nope, looks like you missed the point. I edited my question to further describe what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Since @fg_color is setting the global color it seems the areas you are dealing with are not defined (at least not in this file). So try defining the scrollbar with something like:

```
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">

BODY
{
scrollbar-base-color: orange;
scrollbar-arrow-color: green;
scrollbar-DarkShadow-Color: blue;
}
</STYLE>
```

Let me know if this doesn't work. Pardon the delay i got caught up on another project.

Comment: It didn't really work for what I was trying to accomplish. It's not just the scrollbar borders that are affected. It's all borders. So I just did a recursive search in gedit for all instances of @fg_color and then defined them to the color that I wanted. Thanks for your help, but I think it's just the way the .css was written that is making this difficult...